# jQuery change event on input firing on page load

Tags: jquery, html

Why is the following `JQuery` triggered event running when the document becomes ready in the browser. I have very little experience with `JQuery` so I am kinda stuck with this one.

```
    <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form name="f1" id="f1">Input:
    <input list="br" name="b" id="b">
    <datalist id="br">
        <option value="10">
            <option value="11">
                <option value="12">
                    <option value="100">
                        <option value="101">
    </datalist>
</form>
<br>
<fieldset>
    <legend id="result"></legend>
</fieldset>

<script>
$("#b")
    .change(function () {
    var str = $('#b').val();
    $("#result").text(str);

    $.get("cgi-bin/something.cgi?s=" + str, function (data) {
        $("body")
            .append("Name: " + data.name) 
        .append("Time: " + data.time);
    }, "json");
    alert("Load was performed.");
})
    .change();
</script>
```

Bonus points if you can also tell me why "cgi-bin/something.cgi?s=" + str is not including var `str` in the `Get` request. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `change()` event is triggered on load because it's being called without an argument.  An extremely simplified version of your code looks like this:

```
$("#b").change(function(){ /*do stuff*/ }).change();
```

This can be confusing because the `change()` function acts as either a handler or a trigger, depending on how an argument is passed (see docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/)).

Simply removing the extra `change()` call should do the trick.

Comment: No more right then @charlietfl answer, but you posted first so I awarded you the accept. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

Your code defines a `change` handler, then imediately triggers the `change` event

```
/* define change handler*/
$("#b").change(function(){
   /* code to run when changed*/
})    
/* then trigger change event*/
.change();
```

Since you are triggering the change handler immediately after defining it, it will run immediately. If you don't want this to happen, remove the `.change()` at end

If the `<select>` is not set with `selected` on an option that has value, `$('#b').val()` will be empty string when it first loads, accounting for incorrect url

Also strange that your `<fieldset>` is not contained within `<form>`

Comment: Josh Stafford was accepted as he posted first, but your answer is valid as well. The other issue is with the `$.get("cgi-bin/something.cgi?s=" + str, function (data)` not including the `str`'s value as the append to #result is working currently.

Comment: actually if look at times, mine was first...no biiggy though

Comment: ooops...I actually misread this, i answered correct at first....if `$('#b')` is not set on page load with `selected` will be empty so `str` used for url will be empty